# Otimizar NSPredicate com MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, desempenho, core-data, nspredicate

**Antes de tudo segue meu modelo:**

[image: xcdatamodel]

**Classes:**

```
@interface MMEAlbum : NSManagedObject

... outras propriedades
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *album_upcoming;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;

@end

--------
@interface MMESong : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *song_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *song_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MMEAlbum *album;

@end
```

**Populando o banco:**

```
//Parse album
MMEAlbum *newAlbum              = [MMEAlbum MR_createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newAlbum.album_active           = [albumDic active];
newAlbum.album_banner_text      = [albumDic banner_text];
... demais propriedades

// Parse Songs
for (NSDictionary *songDic in allSongs)
{
MMESong *newSong    = [MMESong MR_createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newSong.song_id     = [songDic id_song];
newSong.song_name   = [songDic name_song];
newSong.album       = newAlbum;
}

//Save context
[self saveDefaultContext];
```

---

Vamos ao problema, em certo momento eu preciso fazer uma busca de uma música pelo nome via `searchBar` e mostrar o resultado em uma tabela:

```
// Esse método é acionado toda vez que uma letra é digitada no teclado
- (NSArray *)searchTracksWith:(NSString *)string
{
NSPredicate *filterTracks = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"song_name contains[c] %@", string];
NSArray *result = [MMESong MR_findAllWithPredicate:filterTracks];

return result;
}
```

*Tenho 80.000(oitenta mil) músicas registradas no banco e quando realizo a busca utilizando o predicado acima além de ser lento ele congela minha view.*

Tentei utilizar esse outro predicado, pesquisando através da raiz pai:

```
NSPredicate *filterTracks = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY songs.song_name contains[c] %@", string];
NSArray *result = [MMEAlbum MR_findAllWithPredicate:filterTracks];
return result;
```

*Melhorou o tempo de resposta, mas nada que agrade muito.*

Alguma ideia de como criar um `NSPredicate` que seja eficiente para esse tipo de consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o problema não é o `NSPredicate`, este tipo de objeto não foi feito para otimizar a performance das suas queries, ele é uma conveniencia para você escrever queries mais digamos "legíveis".

O problema está mais relacionado a concorrência, provavelmente a melhor maneira de você resolver isso, seria usando um `NSManagedObjectContext` em modo concorrente a thread que você está usando (que é muito provavel que seja a main, por isso que você ve a interface congelar durante a execução da query).

Isso é um problema comum e pode ser mais complicado, principalmente se você precisa sincronizar alterações entre uma thread e outra.

Dando uma pesquisada, achei duas referências que podem te ajudar bastante:

1. [A Guide to Core Data Concurrency](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data)
2. [Common Background Practices](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html)

Espero que isso te ajude.

Answer (score 1):

iTSangar,

Tentar colocar esse processo dentro de uma thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

});
```